# Running Apple Store Apps on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Can i run download applications from Apple Store on iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, you cannot, because the App Store apps are compiled for the iPhone (ARM), not the simulator (x86). Sorry.